# The meaning of negative sign in vectors?

Tags: acceleration, vectors, velocity

*if the velocity vector $\overrightarrow{v}=v\widehat{i}$             ,, we define the accelration vector as it's the time derivative of the velocity vector*    $\overrightarrow{a}=(\frac{dv }{dt})\widehat{i}$

We know that when dealing with vectors the neagtive sign means a direction and it doesn't mean a numerical value

My question is as follows: Is the term $\frac{dv }{dt}$  in this equation [ $\overrightarrow{a}=(\frac{dv }{dt})\widehat{i}$] means a scalar numerial value that can be positive or negative in value and it doesn't mean direction but the direction is meant  in the whole structure of vector which is the term ($\overrightarrow{a}$) ?

like an example : if $\overrightarrow{a}= (-5)\widehat{i}$  Is the term ($-5$) a numerical scalar value that represent the coordinates of the vector and  this negative sign doesn't represent a direction but the direction is meant to the whole vector which is ($\overrightarrow{a}$) ?

Comment: Why can't the negative sign mean numerical values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rectangular coordinates, the general equation for the velocity  (or any) vector is
$$\vec v=v_{x}\hat i+v_{y}\hat j+v_{z}\hat k$$ where the values $v_x$, $v_y$ and $v_{z}$ are real numbers that can be positive, negative, or zero.

So the "negative signs" are associated with the specific components of the vector, not to the vector as a whole.

Hope this helps.

Comment: and these negative signs are meant to be just ordinary negative numbers not to mean the direction in it , Am I right ?

Comment: @Mans Yes the negative signs are meant to be ordinary negative numbers, where the numbers are real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

By convention, the magnitude of a vector is always of a non-negative number. So for a vector $\vec{a} = (-5) \hat{\imath}$ the interpretation is as follows

$$ \vec{a}\;\;\; = \underbrace{5}_\text{magnitude}\;\;\; \underbrace{-\hat{\imath}}_\text{direction} $$

Comment: Any vector can be written as $\overrightarrow{a}=$$\begin{bmatrix}
 a_{x}\\a_{y}
 \\a_{z}

\end{bmatrix}$ $=\begin{bmatrix}
 a_{x}\\0
 \\0




\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
a_{y} \\0
 \\0

\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}a_{z}
 \\0
 \\0

\end{bmatrix}$$=a_{x}\begin{bmatrix}
 1\\0
 \\0




\end{bmatrix}+a_{y}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\0
 \\0

\end{bmatrix}+a_{z}\begin{bmatrix}1
 \\0
 \\0

\end{bmatrix}$ ,,the terms $(a_{x},a_{y},a_{z})$ are real numbers that scale and make orientation of the unit vectors so this terms are just number and don't carry a direction in it

Comment: The magnitude of any vector is denoted by $\left\| \overrightarrow{a} \right\|=\sqrt{(a_{x})^2+(a_{y})^2+(a_{z})^2}$ *which is always a positive number* and the magnitude is not the $(a_{x},a_{y},a_{z})$

Comment: @Mans - the components of the basis vectors can have negative numbers. I am not sure if you are agreeing with me or not. This is a special case where the negative sign is a common factor for the entire vector.

Comment: What I meant in my comment that in the component of a vector if there a component with negative sign like : $\overrightarrow{v}=-8{\widehat{i}}$ $=(-8){\widehat{i}}$ so this negative sign is taken to the number itself not to mean a direction

Comment: @Mans - If your basis vector is $\hat{i}$ then $\hat{i} \cdot \vec{v} = -8$ means negative eight units along the $\hat{i}$ direction. But by convention this is interpreted as 8 units in the negative $\hat{i}$ direction.

Comment: our basis vector is $\widehat{i}$ if we write $\overrightarrow{v}=(-8)\widehat{i}$ as I've written $a_{x}$ or $a_{y}$ or $a_{z}$ are meant to be scalars and if they are negative it's meant that the vector has a length but in the negative direction like : $\overrightarrow{v}=(-8)\widehat{i}$ any number that is beside $\widehat{i}$ or $\widehat{j}$ or $\widehat{k}$ are just ordinary numbers and doesn't mean anything else  you multiply this number to this unit vector you can also check this in Thomas calculus book in the chapter of vectors